# How to view echo within a php file that is called from a form button submission in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am troubleshooting some ajax code but I can never see the echo statements because the ajax file is called from a button submission in a form.  How can I prevent the page from reloading so that I can see the echo statements

I suspect  within the form

`<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">`

a revision would resolve my issue??

Answer (score 1):

To prevent preloading page add

```
preventDefault();
```

at the begining of *checkform* method or if it doesn't work create another method which will be called on form submit, for example:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: bare with me, but I am new to programming, preventDefault() at teh beginning of checkform(Pform1) did not help do I simply create another function and then call it from onsubmit??

Comment: If you will use the method from my example you don't need to call it on form submit because jQuery will catch form submission event and call the method.